# It's possible to force a graceful shutdown when you kill a QEMU process?

Tags: virtual-machine, qemu, signals, shutdown

I'm working with a Ubuntu VM with QEMU, I understand that when the Host (Mac M1 in my case) makes a shutdown sends a SIGTERM to all processes, but when arrives the signal to QEMU the Ubuntu does nothing, so the QEMU dies like a SIGKILL.

Exists any option/workaround to force a graceful shutdown on VM when QEMU receives a SIGTERM?

Comment: Is your guest OS running `qemu-guest-agent`?

Comment: Nop, but I just installed and started, and it seems that nothing new happens (graceful shutdown) when killing the qemu process